# Thicker Border vs. Template

Tags: html, css

I've had a similiar issue like this before and trying to finally get it corrected. If you notice in the js fiddle there seems to be a thicker border above the actions div and I'm trying to find out why there is and there isn't in the template that I purchased.

http://jsfiddle.net/pGFfa/

Template:http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/files/templates/admin/peachv1.2/Template/forms.html

EDIT:

I updated my page with the real intended page but look at the actions area and there still is a border on the left and right. Not sure why.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which browser/version are you seeing this in?

Comment: ^^^ I don't see a difference in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double border is because of the bottom border of the content div. The div in the template has rule ".box .content.with-actions" applied which says "border-bottom: 0 none;". The content div in your fiddle doesn't have that rule so it has a bottom border and also the actions div has a top border hence the thicker line appearance.

The difference is that the content div in the template also has the "with-actions" class while the one in your fiddle doesn't. Just add that class and the problem disappears.

Comment: I updated my page with the real intended page but look at the actions area and there still is a border on the left and right. Not sure why.

Comment: I don't quite follow you, do you have a fiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: sorry about that here it is I thought it updated for me http://jsfiddle.net/jkNFw/

Comment: OK, 2 problems noted: one is that you've inserted your 'actions' div in the wrong container (i.e. in the content div). You need to pull it one level higher, as the last element in the form, after the 'content' div. Second is that in your css you have usually classes called "content" but your HTML uses things like "content-form". This is why your classes don't match and you have no left-right borders on the 'content' div. Just replace "content-form" class name with "content" in your HTML and it looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a double border plus the radius being applied to the bottom and not the top of the form container.

Answer (score 0):

In content.css, try changing:

```css
.box .content-form { border: 1px solid #C8C8C8; }
```

to:

```css
.box .content-form { border: 1px solid #C8C8C8; border-bottom: none; }
```

Comment: This may not be fully correct guessing from the template markup. I don't think the author intended that all .content-form boxes have no bottom border, only those with no actions below. That's why he created the 'with-actions' class. A content div with no actions below will not have any bottom border with your solution.

Comment: The point is that the issue is in the CSS and the OP can mess with it to their heart's content to get it to look exactly how they want.  My suggestion was simply an immediate reduction of the thickness of the border.  I didn't have time to dissect everything.  It was simply the first thing I tried that removed that extra thickness. The OP should know where to go from there.

Comment: @downvoter - There's no reason this should be downvoted. It was a useful answer that points to the issue.